# Environment variable undefined error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mean-stack

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const dotenv = require('dotenv');


const error = require('./middleware/errorMiddlewareHandler');

const usersRoute = require('./routes/userRoute');

dotenv.config();

require('./config/dbConnect')();


const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;


//passing body data
app.use(express.json());

//user routes

//routes
app.use('/api/users', usersRoute);
console.log(process.env.JWT_KEY);




//error middleware
app.use(error.errorMiddlewareHandler);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

whenever I run the code terminal is showing like

**undefined**

**Server is listening on port 3000**

I have already assigned the **JWT_KEY** correctly

JWT_KEY=stackoverflow

So any body knows the problem just let me know

Comment: echo $JWT_KEY on bash is returning stackoverflow?

Comment: I would guess the property isn't assigned correctly--how *specifically* are you assigning it?

Comment: How do you run the app?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the result of `config()` (make sure the `.env`-file is in the root-dir in that case) via :

```
require('dotenv').config()

const result = dotenv.config()

if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}

console.log(result.parsed)
```

and see if it configures correctly. -> see more infos on [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

I personally prefer to use a `env_config.js` file processing my envs and require it whenever needed (i.E. in `app.js`).

env_config.js:

```
var path = require('path');


const dotenvAbsolutePath = path.join(__dirname, '.env');

/* INFO: Require dotenv package for retieving and setting env-vars at runtime via absoliute path due to pkg */

  const dotenv = require('dotenv').config({
    path: dotenvAbsolutePath
  });
  if (dotenv.error) {
    console.log(`ERROR WHILE READING ENV-VARS:${dotenv.error}`);
    throw dotenv.error;
  }

module.exports = {
  nodeEnv: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  nodePort: process.env.NODE_PORT,
  deviceLocation: process.env.DEVICE_LOCATION,
  hostWLC: process.env.HOST_WLC,
  hostPostgresql: process.env.HOST_POSTGRESQL,
  portPostgresql: process.env.PORT_POSTGRESQL,
  dbPostgresql: process.env.DB_POSTGRESQL,
  userPostgresql: process.env.USER_POSTGRESQL,
  pwdPostgresql: process.env.PWD_POSTGRESQL,
  hostMQTT: process.env.HOST_MQTT,
  portMQTT: process.env.PORT_MQTT,
  userMQTT: process.env.USER_MQTT,
  pwdMQTT: process.env.PWD_MQTT,
};
```

app.js:

```
const { nodePort } = require('./env-config');
....
...
..
app.listen(nodePort, () => console.log(`Node's Express someApp is listening on Port ${nodePort}..`));
```

.env file (in root dir):

```
NODE_ENV=******
NODE_PORT=******
DEVICE_LOCATION=******
HOST_WLC=******
HOST_POSTGRESQL=******
PORT_POSTGRESQL=******
DB_POSTGRESQL=******
USER_POSTGRESQL=******
PWD_POSTGRESQL=******
HOST_MQTT=******
PORT_MQTT=******
USER_MQTT=******
PWD_MQTT=******
```

**Normal usage** according to official docs:

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

> Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE. For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

> `process.env` now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file.

```
const db = require('db')
db.connect({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS
})
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the file require and configure dotenv
require("dotenv").config()
Delete the other configs you have already

Comment: Why do you think that will solve the issue? - It's perfectly fine to first require the env-module and then call its config()-func -> no need to do it all at one since someone might need to pass additional args to the config() at as later stage (such as a location varying from root for example)..